PhD supervisor gave me topics to study before joining PhD but I am studying for TOEFL and GRE Mathematics Test

It was a genuine question( I think) and I have acted on the advice given by the community. I think I got downvotes because people thought I shouldn't have asked this question as I want to go for PhD at the institute at which I am offered fellowship rather than apply for USA but I still asked this question here! Actually, I was looking for 2nd opinion by people who already are doing PhD or even seniors and I was for many days confused earlier!  Is there anything that can be done to change so many downvotes?

I am an upcoming PhD student in Mathematics in Central Europe and my 1st semester started on 19 September 2024. As I was contacting my PhD supervisor earlier by mail on 16 August 2024 , she told me that I should read some topics related to my research area. I still am in my home country (3 rd world) as I am still collecting visa documents and I have not given visa interview but I have applied for Visa interview appointment date.
I was preparing for GRE general test till 17 August as I was also thinking of applying to USA before I got the decision for this university in Central Europe. But it is now clear to me that I will go to this university in Central Europe only.
So, after my gre general exam on 17th August, I took some rest and my mother was telling me to wait till I get the official offer letter by post mail which I have to deposit ( hard copy) at embassy. If my mother hadn't stopped me earlier, I would have started preparing documents earlier.
I started to prepare documents for visa on 5 September and many different documents are needed for long term residence permit.
I used to collect documents and ask information in morning and use to have a lot of free time in evenings on some days but I didn't studied any of the topics my PhD supervisor gave me.
I instead on  monday of last week, paid the fees of TOEFL and Gre mathematics subject test and started preparing for them despite the fact that I surely want to go to Central Europe for my PhD. My TOEFL test is scheduled at 13 October, 2024 and GRE mathematics subject test at 25 October, 2024.I did this as I used to have a lot of free time since past week and I thought of utilizing it.
There are no classes in my university for PhD's but the 4 courses are to be self studied and exam given to professors after confirming exam dates with them.

Should I stop preparing for TOEFL and GRE mathematics subject test and should only focus on what topics my supervisor gave to me to study?

I am quite confused and would appreciate some guidance!

I'm a bit confused - it sounds like you will not use the GRE subject test or TOEFL, and you're asking whether you should prepare for them anyways instead of preparing for the PhD program you are already admitted to and planning to attend?

@BryanKrause yes you are right

Given that you will not use the GRE subject test or TOEFL and are already accepted to a PhD program you plan to attend, why would you study for the GRE subject test or TOEFL?

This makes no sense at all. You say you “surely” want to study in Central Europe and you’ve found an advisor, but now in your “free time” you’ve decided to study for the US admissions exams? Despite the fact that your advisor told you to study something else? You’ve been trying to get an opportunity like this for years now, it’s time to stop this nonsense and start spending every hour doing what it takes to be successful in the program you are actually attending, not studying for random exams for programs on other continents.

This is complete nonsense, you got into a program, but you are trying to renege on it by preparing for applications to North America. In doing so you are not taking your upcoming advisor seriously and not studying what they asked you to. Do you want a bit of a reality check? If you are having trouble juggling some reading and preparing for basic entrance exams at the same time, you are not some superstar that can afford to play sides as you ladder climb to a better degree.

"I didn't studied any of the topics my PhD supervisor gave me." "I used to have a lot of free time since past week and I thought of utilizing it." These don’t go together. It looks like you don’t actually have free time, you are procrastinating - using the time you should spend on your PhD for other things.


Should I stop preparing for TOEFL and GRE mathematics subject test and should only focus on what topics my supervisor gave to me to study?

Yes. You don't need the TOEFL or GRE Math anymore. The GRE Math is by and large only required for graduate admissions to US PhD programs. Since you're not studying there, it's irrelevant.
TOEFL could be relevant for stuff like citizenship applications, or perhaps before you get admitted if you're studying in an English-language country. But since you're already admitted, it's again irrelevant; if your university needs you to improve your English skills, they'll have ways arranged, e.g. the University of Hamburg has a "University Language Center" that teaches English.
Since the TOEFL and GRE Math are irrelevant to you, you should focus on the topics your supervisor gave you.

Assuming that you still want/need to take the exams, it is likely that you need to do both. It would be a mistake to ignore the supervisor.
Time management is the key. Set aside some hours per day/week for each task and take notes on everything as you go. In fact, switching between topics can actually be advantageous based on how the brain works. After looking at something extensively for a while, switching gives the brain the opportunity to integrate things. Making notes as you go, rather than just trying to memorize things also helps.
However, if you don't need to take either or both of the exams, you can just skip that and focus on the papers. Having paid for the exams doesn't require you to sit them.
